# Combine multiple locations into one

Tags: nginx

How could i Combine multiple locations into one ?

Example :

```
location /A{
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.0:3000;
}

location /B{
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.0:3000;
}
```

Convert to

```
location ~ ^/(A|B) {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.0:3000;           
}
```

but the converted is not working ?
so how to solve it

Comment: this answer might be felpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/564127/nginx-location-regex-for-multiple-paths

Comment: Combining two prefix-based locations into one regex-based location will degrade performance. Evaluating regular expression in NGINX will always be slower than matching against prefixes.